# Where not exists condition syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to exclude records which does match some criteria. I am trying to use use WHERE NOT Exists syntax.

But doesn't work.

```
select b.*
from Staging.Siebel.UCM."S_CONTACT" b
where not exists (select * 
                  from Staging.Siebel.UCM.“CX_CDI_MERGE” c 
                  where b.cid_num = c.X_NEW_CDI_ID
                 );
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Those fancy quotes (`“`, `”`) are really intentional? They're not the regular ones... Maybe it's just that, replace them with regular ones (`"`).

Comment: @AndyLester the message i get on dremio is  " 
Failure parsing the query."

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you should be able to use `select ... where not in (select ...)`.